# llamar a un RFC en SAP HANA con asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, sap, hana

como se hace el llamado a un RFC de SAP HANA desde asp.net core 6 ?
que conectores se utilizan ??, o como se consiguen ??
Si pudieran compartirlos por favor.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: pues está clara la pregunta, como se hace el llamado a un RFC en sap hana, con que conector ??? y por favor si tienen el código de como se emplea, por que tengo entendido que no se usa el mismo conector que se utiliza en SAP NetWeaver.